# use the result of YOLOv8 for pyzbar

Tags: python, opencv, yolo

I want to pass the result from the YOLOv8 to the decode function so that the barcodes are read from it.

My program code is:

```
model = YOLO("yolov8n.pt")

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
while True:
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    results = model.predict(source=frame, show=True, conf=0.70, stream=True, device=0)
    decode(results.numpy())
    if cv2.waitKey(10) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break
cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

When I do this, I get the following error message:

```
AttributeError: 'generator' object has no attribute 'numpy'
```

Additionally I want to preprocess the frame with kraken.binarization.nlbin() is this possible, if so how?

Comment: What do you want to pass? The image crops or bboxes into decode?

Comment: The image so that pyzbar can read the barcode from it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you read the documentation for Ultralytics' [predict](https://docs.ultralytics.com/predict/) you will see that return does not contain any image.

You have to customize your predictor to return the original image so that you can use the bboxes present in `results` in order to crop the image. Then you can pass the crops to `decode`:

```py
import cv2
from ultralytics.yolo.engine.model import YOLO
from pyzbar.pyzbar import decode

    
def on_predict_batch_end(predictor):
    # results -> List[batch_size]
    path, im, im0s, vid_cap, s = predictor.batch
    predictor.results = zip(predictor.results, im0s)
         

model = YOLO("yolov8n.pt")
model.add_callback("on_predict_batch_end", on_predict_batch_end)
results = model.predict(source="0", show=True, stream=True)
for i, (result, im0) in enumerate(results):
    boxes = result.boxes
    for box in boxes:
        xyxy = box.xyxy[0]  # get box coordinates in (top, left, bottom, right) format
        t = int(xyxy[0].item())
        l = int(xyxy[1].item())
        b = int(xyxy[2].item())
        r = int(xyxy[3].item())
        crop_img = im0[l:r, t:b]
        d = decode(crop_img)
        print(d)
        cv2.imshow('YOLO V8 crop', crop_img)
```

This gives me the following output (I had a QR code on my phone screen) which I anonymized for obvious reasons:

```bash
0: 480x640 2 persons, 1 cell phone, 9.7ms
[Decoded(data=b'https://wa.me/qr/XXXXXXXXXXXXXX', type='QRCODE', rect=Rect(left=105, top=248, width=90, height=95), polygon=[Point(x=105, y=343), Point(x=193, y=341), Point(x=195, y=251), Point(x=111, y=248)], quality=1, orientation=None)]
```

Comment: @Mike_B The code does not seem to work.  I only get the following output: tensor([[280.00000, 205.00000, 354.00000, 258.00000,   0.75860,   0.00000]], device='cuda:0')
(480, 640, 3)

Comment: Code:    
`model = YOLO("yolov8n.pt")
model.add_callback("on_predict_batch_end", on_predict_batch_end)
results = model.predict(source="0", show=True, conf=0.70, stream=True)
for i, (result, im0) in enumerate(results):
      boxes = result.boxes
      for box in boxes:
       xyxy = box.xyxy[0]
       t = int(xyxy[0].item())
       l = int(xyxy[1].item())
       b = int(xyxy[2].item())
       r = int(xyxy[3].item())
       crop_img = im0[l:r, t:b]
       decode(crop_img)`

`Expected I would have the following output:
Decoded(
   data=b'Foramenifera', type='CODE128',`
    ....

Comment: Updated code. If it is not working for you. Please explain clearly what isn't working. This works fine on my side.

Comment: I have identified the problem, but do not know how to solve it. I only get a green screen on my JetsonNano, after my search I found the following suggested solutions for OpenCV:
https://github.com/JetsonHacksNano/CSI-Camera/blob/master/simple_camera.py

`cap = cv2.VideoCapture('nvarguscamerasrc ! video/x-raw(memory:NVMM), width=3280, height=2464, format=(string)NV12, framerate=(fraction)20/1 ! nvvidconv ! video/x-raw, format=(string)BGRx ! videoconvert ! video/x-raw, format=(string)BGR ! appsink' , cv2.CAP_GSTREAMER)`

How can I implement the gstreamer_pipeline function in the code above?

Comment: Please, stop adding follow up questions in the comment section. Open a new question if needed. I won't answer this in the comments for obvious reasons. Acknowledge the effort spent in the answer if it provided a solution to your question.